# Flutter type 'RxList<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>>'

Tags: flutter

The widget I am attempting to produce is a dropdown button and I am using flutter [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package for my state management.

The controller:

```
  // Getter and Setter for Downdown List Item
  RxList<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>> _dropdownMenuItems = [].obs;
  set setDropdownValues(value) => _dropdownMenuItems(value);
  List<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>> get getDropdownValues => _dropdownMenuItems
    .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
      value: e.value,
      child: Text(e.value.name))).toList();

  // Getter and Setter for Items Selected from the dropdown
  Rx<ListItem> _selectedItem = ListItem().obs;
  set setSelectedItem(value) => _selectedItem(value);
  get getSelectedItem => _selectedItem.value;

  // OnInit
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    setDropdownValues = buildDropDownMenuItems(); // Sets dropdown list
    setSelectedItem = getDropdownValues[0].value; // Sets selected item as the first entry to the list
  }

  // Sample to populate the Dropdown List
  List<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>> buildDropDownMenuItems() {
    
    List<ListItem> _dropdownItems = [
      ListItem(value: 1, name: "Recent"),
      ListItem(value: 2, name: "Oldest"),
    ];

    List<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>> items = [];
    for (ListItem listItem in _dropdownItems) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(listItem.name),
          value: listItem,
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }
```

The widget:

```
  DropdownButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
    value: controller.getSelectedItem,
    items: controller.getDropdownValues)
```

The error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty):
type 'RxList<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>>'
```

Am I assigning the wrong type for the RxList? Am I mapping it to the list incorrectly?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello can i ask you a question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

The only thing I needed to do was convert the obs list to the type it was referring to.

So, previously it was

```
RxList<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>> _dropdownMenuItems = [].obs;
```

I have updated it to be

```
RxList<DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>> _dropdownMenuItems = <DropdownMenuItem<ListItem>>[].obs;
```